# Предлагаю рассмотреть возможность канонизации веб-адреса проекта stackoverflow на HTTPS

Tags: предложение, https

Предлагаю рассмотреть возможность канонизации веб-адреса проекта **stackoverflow**,с HTTPS, HTTP, и всех прочих вариантов,  на **HTTPS**, с рассмотрением возможности редиректа.

Посмотрев исходный **HTML** код **stackoverflow**, я не увидел там ссылку на каноническую страницу сайта.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.org" />
```

Поэтому, сейчас трафик может разделяться между HTTPS, HTTP, и другими вариантами. Даже не смотря на то, что поисковые системы пытаются в автоматическом режиме определять каноническую страницу сайта.

К примеру, **http://stackoverflow.com** и **https://stackoverflow.com** - это два разных сайта. Если будет использоваться два протокола, будет идти разделение трафика. Что в свою очередь будет негативно сказываться на ранжировании в поисковых системах.

**Если ставите минус, желательно, если вас это не затруднит, описывайте пожалуйста причину.**

Comment: Описываю причину минуса: мне не нравится, когда мне запрещают ставить минусы без указания причины.

Comment: @ Утка Учится Уму Но это нормально. Вы своим минусом приносите  вред как этому вопросу, сообществу stackoverflow,  так и человеку который его задал. И этот вред должен быть оправдан тем человеком, кто его причиняет.  Другими словами - сбили взлетающий самолёт, объясните причину ) Может там и вправду находились террористы для совершения второго 11 сентября, а может там были обычные граждане и вам просто показалось что они террористы.

Comment: Вы в своем вопросе фактически одновременно вынесли две темы, одну, объявленную в заголовке, на которую мне все равно. Вторую, объявленную в двух последних абзацах, к которой я отношусь резко отрицательно. В результате я совершенно обоснованно и оправданно голосую против.

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму Спасибо! Я Вас понял и исправил описание своего вопроса.

Comment: ок, минус убрал

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму Спасибо!)

Answer (score 4):

Про `rel="canonical"` ничего сказать не могу.

Что касается поисковиков, во-первых, полагаю, они давно умеют обрабатывать наличие одинаковых страниц по двум протоколам. Во-вторых, SO и ruSO давно уже в топе поиска, так что маловероятно, что в этом плане можно что-то улучшить.

А вот теперь что касается редиректа. Я считаю, что пользователи имеют право сами решать, каким протоколом им пользоваться. Поэтому надо все внутренние ссылки сделать через `//` без указания протокола, что позводит сохранять протокол при переходе по ним.

А вот принудительный https не нужен. Так что я против редиректа.

Comment: Ну, тут проблема в том, что приходя из поисковика пользователь попадает на случайную версию сайта из двух... Является ли это нормальным - не знаю.